# Subtotals in PivotTables for Calculates Fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have added a Calculated Field that takes the value in each row for each column (3 columns) and divides it by 300,000. I am only in need of the last result, i.e. the Grand Total for each row divided by 300,000. However, I don’t seem to be able to hide each column subtotal for each row.

Better yet, is it possible to insert a new field to a PivotTable and that one only makes calculations based on the Grand Total of each row.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Your question is not clear at all without samples.

Comment: maybe share a sample picture of your current pivot table structure, and another picture of the expected output?